# $_GET value will not post to update record

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

I am using a single page submission form to create and also edit a record. It creates the record fine and will populate the form and update it if I define the record id myself.

It will not update if I try and pull in the `$_GET` value.

Here is what I have:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$guests = Guest::find_by_id($id);
} 
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $guest = new Guest();
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $guest->id = $id;
    }
    $guest->name = $_POST['guest_name'];
    $guest->info = $_POST['guest_info'];
    $guest->image_path = $_POST['guest_image_path'];
    $guest->sc_player = $_POST['guest_sc_player'];

    if($guest->update()) {
        $message = "Uploaded successfully.";
    } else {
        $message = join("<br />", $guest->errors);
    }
}
```

It works if I replace the second if statement with `$guest->id = "14"`

Comment: Are you sure $_GET['id'] is set? Have you tried a var_dump($_GET['id'])?

Comment: Your request can't be both a POST and a GET request. The two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I echoed $_GET['id'] somewhere on the page to test to see if its working and it returned the right id.

Comment: @meagar: what if i post to `page.php?id=3` ? ;)

Comment: heres the html form http://jsfiddle.net/TJPrn/2/

Comment: ahhh yeh. Just needed the form action to include the id!

Comment: I don't see the id in that form... Where do you set it? In the form action? Or an input element in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ID I can't see it anywhere, where is it set?

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding the id to the form action, before it was just action="save_guest.php" . And the id was passed in through the header.

Comment: Good, as long as it works, that's why are we here, we all have problems ;)